# Inno Setup: Hide icon in titlebar?

Tags: winapi, inno-setup

Is it possible to hide icon and name of the program in titlebar of the installer using Win API? I guess that text cen be changed by [SetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but what about icon?

[image]

Comment: What about setting icon to blank (transparent .ico :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set border style to "dialog" and unset the small icon.

```pascal
WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
SendMessage(WizardForm.Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0);
```

Though this way you also lose the "minimize" and "maximize" buttons. Only the "close" button prevails.

[image]

---

The other way is to set a transparent icon as @Slappy suggested.